# Vaadin 7 make application SEO ready

Tags: seo, vaadin, vaadin7, google-crawlers, prerender

Google Ajax-crawling instructions say the `!#` is actually transformed into `?_escaped_fragment_` by the google crawler.

I'd like to prepare my Vaadin 7 application to be SEO ready for Google search engine so could you please tell me if there is any out of the box functionality  that will simplify that process by handling a following requests with `?_escaped_fragment_` ?

If there is no out of the box solution - what is the right way in order to implement this ?

Or another idea - is it possible to use [Prerender.io](https://prerender.io) together with Vaadin ?

**UPDATED**

Looks like nowadays Google is able to crawl, render, and index the `#!` URLs.

```
Q: My site currently follows your recommendation and supports _escaped_fragment_. Would my site stop getting indexed now that you've deprecated your recommendation?
A: No, the site would still be indexed. In general, however, we recommend you implement industry best practices when you're making the next update for your site. Instead of the _escaped_fragment_ URLs, we'll generally crawl, render, and index the #! URLs.
```

https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html

Can someone please confirm that Vaadin application can be successfully crawled by Google bot ?

Comment: Haven't had the need yet to look into SEO, so I don't know if these are of any help to you but there are a few older discussions on the Vaadin forum [here](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/1400878/1400877) (this seems to be not helpful at all) and [here](https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/95600/95599) (this seems a bit more _eloquent_)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [volga](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/volga) addon and the related [blog post](https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/adventures-in-seo).

> Volga is a Vaadin add-on that helps you to add meta data to your
>   Vaadin applications, which will help social media services and search
>   engines better interpret your application.